# How do I configure integration tests using rspec 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, rspec2

I need to have different settings for my unit tests and different settings for my integration tests. Example

For unit tests, I would like to do

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
```

And for integration tests, I would like to do

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```

Also, before the start of an integration test, I would like to make sure that solr is started. Hence I want to be able to call

```
config.before(:suite) do
  SunspotStarter.start
end
```

BUT, only for integration tests. I do not want to start my solr if its a unit test.

How do I keep their configurations separate? Right now, I have solved this by keeping my integration tests in a folder outside the spec folder, which has its own spec_helper. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

My solution might be a bit hackish, but as far as I tested it should work.

I noticed that `config.include` takes a `type` argument, so it could be <del>ab</del>used to execute arbitrary blocks of code like so:

```
module UnitTestSettings
  def self.included(base)
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
  end
end

module IntegrationTestSettings
  def self.included(base)
    WebMock.allow_net_connect!

    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.before(:suite) do
        SunspotStarter.start
      end
    end

  end
end

Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include UnitTestSettings, :type => :model
  config.include IntegrationTestSettings, :type => :integration
end
```

Drop this in a file in the support folder and you should be good to go, although I haven't actually tested the code. Also, I'm quite sure there is a better way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a type for a before / after block, in the same way that you can for the include statement. So you could do the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :model) do
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    WebMock.allow_net_connect!
  end

  config.before(:suite, type: :request) do
    SunspotStarter.start
  end
end
```